# jQuery slide sibling element

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to use jQuery to slide an element. I use a sibling div to trigger the animation, which does work, however the trigger div does not slide with it, and I'm extremely confused as to why it does not since other examples I've seen achieve this with zero other animation effects.

I'm using this for the animation effect:

```
$('.toggle').unbind('click').click(function(event) {
    $(this).siblings('.content').animate({'width': 'toggle'}, 200, 'swing');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I outlined the issue in a complete example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/qcBz7/

Thanks!

Comment: It's all about positioning and floating the elements. An absolute element does not move it's siblings.

Comment: Yes but I've seen code that achieves this with both elements as absolutes so I was extremely confused :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the js to this:

```
var go = true;
$('.toggle').on('click', function(event) {
    if (go) {
        $(this).parent('.box').animate({marginRight: '0px'}, 200, 'swing');
        go = false;
    } else if (!go) {
        $(this).parent('.box').animate({marginRight: '-100px'}, 200, 'swing');
        go = true;
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

and i think it does what you want it to, let me know if you need changes.

Your biggest issue was the css, so I made some changes there as well, you can see in the fiddle.

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/fXmDK/